# How to fix git log output (missing lines in less)?

Tags: git, terminal

I have two different servers each running a Ubuntu installation. On both of them, I have set `env LESS=-FerX` which makes sure that git log output is displayed nicely. Also, line wrapping is turned on.

On one of the servers, if I run `git log` and there are dynamically-wrapped lines, the topmost lines disappear.

For example:

```
log --pretty='format:%C(3)[%h] %Cgreen%an%Creset%n %cd %s %Cred%d%Creset' --graph
```

Output on Server 1:

```
* [1234457] John Doe
| Date fooooo bar baz fooooo bar baz fooooo bar baz fooooo bar baz fooooo bar baz
fooooo bar baz fooooo bar baz fooooo bar baz fooooo bar baz fooooo bar baz fooooo
bar baz
* [4567890] Richard Miles
| Date fooooo bar baz
:
```

Output on Server 2:

```
fooooo bar baz fooooo bar baz fooooo bar baz fooooo bar baz fooooo bar baz fooooo
bar baz
* [4567890] Richard Miles
| Date fooooo bar baz
* [0815123] Mary Major
| Date fooooo bar baz fooooo bar baz fooooo bar baz
:
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Just a guess at trouble shooting: If you use the `--no-pager` option does it change anything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Again, I find the answer to my own question only minutes after asking.

Turns out the problem was the `-r` parameter to `less`. It should have been a `-R` instead.

From the manpage:

```
-R or --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS
          Like  -r,  but  only ANSI "color" escape sequences are output in "raw" form.
          Unlike -r, the screen appearance is  maintained  correctly  in  most  cases.
```

For some reson not known to me, the lower-case `-r` works fine on of the other server.

Comment: I also ran into this problem but the less -r was coming from git config core.pager (which another answer discusses) rather than my own environment. Changing core.pager to less -R solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you know this, and you might have tried it, but since you don't mention it:

`man git config` contains (emphasis mine):

```
core.pager
```

> The command that git will use to paginate output. Can be overridden with the GIT_PAGER environment variable. Note that git sets the LESS environment variable to FRSX if it is unset when it runs the pager. One can change these settings by setting the LESS variable to some other value. Alternately, these settings can be overridden on a project or global basis by setting the core.pager option. Setting core.pager has no affect on the LESS environment variable behaviour above, so if you want to override git’s default settings this way, you need to be explicit. **For example, to disable the S option in a backward compatible manner, set core.pager to less -+$LESS -FRX**. This will be passed to the shell by git, which will translate the final command to LESS=FRSX less -+FRSX -FRX.