# ANSI color in git is not displayed correctly

Tags: git, bash

Recently, I switched to SLES 11. I found a problem for git command. All the ANSI color could not be rendered. Instead, it shows the ANSI code like this:

***ESC[33m***commit 0a02124a0fd85c1f0094bcdf15bac1645e3c8630ESC[m

note: the ansi color in 'ls' works very well.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983305/how-to-fix-git-log-output-missing-lines-in-less - assuming that you take into account sehe's answer. (I really don't know why people are trying to set `LESS` in order to help Git out - it knows what it needs.)

Comment: I had already set LESS to use other settings.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try setting your `LESS` environment variable to include the `-R` option:

```
LESS=-R git grep ...
```

If this works, add `export LESS=-R` to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` or similar shell startup file.

```
   -R or --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS
          Like -r, but only ANSI "color" escape sequences are
          output in "raw" form.  Unlike -r, the screen
          appearance is maintained correctly in most cases.
          ANSI "color" escape sequences are sequences of the
          form:

               ESC [ ... m

          where the "..." is zero or more color specification
          characters
```

Comment: You should also be able to muck with the core.pager config parameter. I don't think just `-R` is ideal for Git - it really prefers FRSX - and in fact will set it to that if you haven't already set LESS in your environment.

Comment: @Jefromi: I suggest adding that as an answer, it's easily worth ten points. :)

Answer (score 31):

The problem, as others have noted, is that your terminal is fine, but when Git invokes the pager, it's not interpreting the ANSI color codes correctly.

I'd start out by *unsetting* `LESS` in your environment; it sounds like you might have previously been setting it to something obscuring what Git needs. If that solves it, there you are. If you really must customize `LESS`, note that Git starts out with `FRSX` as default, so be wary of changing those if you don't need to.

If you *do* for whatever reason want `LESS` in your environment different from what you want for Git, the ideal way to deal with Git and the pager is through the `core.pager` config variable. To quote the manpage:

> The command that git will use to paginate output. Can be overridden with the GIT_PAGER environment variable. Note that git sets the LESS environment variable to FRSX if it is unset when it runs the pager. One can change these settings by setting the LESS variable to some other value. Alternately, these settings can be overridden on a project or global basis by setting the core.pager option. Setting core.pager has no affect on the LESS environment variable behaviour above, so if you want to override git’s default settings this way, you need to be explicit. For example, to disable the S option in a backward compatible manner, set core.pager to `less -+$LESS -FRX`. This will be passed to the shell by git, which will translate the final command to `LESS=FRSX less -+FRSX -FRX`.

That, combined with some knowledge of the options you want, should get you where you want to be. (The fancy backward-compatible method works by disabling all options currently in `LESS`, then adding back in the ones you want.)

Answer (score 21):

In git, you can change your pager to use the `-R` option:

```
git config --global core.pager "less -R"
```

Comment: I had to to first unset it, and then put `less -R` in quotes. Worked though.

Answer (score 7):

For me, this did not work:

`git config --global core.pager less -R`

So instead i appended the following to my ~/.gitconfig file

```
 [core]
     pager = less -R
```

To test it i did

`git log --graph --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%Creset%C(blue)%d%Creset %C(white bold)%s%Creset %C(white dim)(by %an %ar)%Creset" --all`

Comment: you can also try the "--no-pager" switch. For example "git --no-graph diff "

Answer (score 5):

OK, I got it. This problem is to do with the variable LESS.

following line resolve this problem:

```
export LESS="-erX"
```

Comment: You should use "-eRX" intead of "-erX" (per sarnold's answer, above). If you use "-r" than less will pass other control characters straight through (which you probably don't want) and less does not correctly determine the number of lines of output so some scroll off the screen (which you definitely don't want).

The use of "-e" and "-X" have nothing to do with interpreting color escape sequences. "-e" causes less to automatically exit the second time you hit the end of file and "-X" "Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal."

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. But why I need to configure a git in one machine and no need on another? I want to fix the source of the problem because

> git config --global core.pager "less -R"

looks like a workaround for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with ANSI color escape sequences in Git for Windows v2.7.1   in Laravel Artisan and Symfony consoles. Here mentioned `LESS` solution didn't solve the problem.

Since Git for Windows opens terminal with `bash --login -i`, this line entered after terminal started did work for me:

```
bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoever ever winds up here, in my case it was solved by setting core.pager to an empty string, instead of unsetting it:

```
git config --global core.pager ''
```

This was from https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration