# Using a different application to colourize diff output in git

Tags: git, diff, patch, git-diff

I want to use [cdiff](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cdiff) to colourize my diff output when using git. I could pass the output from git commands through cdiff, but I'd like to know if it's possible to not have to do this.

Specifically, when I use `git log -p`, I want it to use cdiff to colourize the output, when I use `git commit -p`, I want it to use cdiff to colourize the output. I'd like to tell git to not do the colouring itself, and to instead use this extra programme.

How do I do this?

Comment: Look at http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, git produces its [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) itself, without delegating to any third party tool: I don't see an easy way in [`git config`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) to transfer that to an external program.
See for instance "[`contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/79fcbf7e703ca5805ebd46b2c7e09d0703f1c1ff/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L216-L260)" (tested in [`t/t4026-color.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t4026-color.sh)).

Then Git calls the pager which you can configure as shown in "[ANSI color in git is not displayed correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8484167/6309)".