# powershell_ise git log output format broken but powershell is okay

Tags: git, powershell

I'm setting up Powershell_ISE to use git.exe, Powershell works but Powershell_ISE seems to break with exposed format escapes visible:

```
C:\Users\rupert\projects\scratch [master]> git log --color --decorate --graph
* [33mcommit d628ab69ff7150f392fe548ecabbd8f5107dc2d1
          [m[33m ([m[1;36mHEAD -> [m[1;32mmaster[m[33m)[m**
  Author: Rupert <rupert@email.au>
  Date:   Tue Jun 6 18:58:02 2017 +1000

      blank project

C:\Users\rupert\projects\scratch [master]> Get-PSReadlineOption

C:\Users\rupert\projects\scratch [master]> Get-PSReadlineOption -Verbose

C:\Users\rupert\projects\scratch [master]> git log  --decorate --graph
* commit d628ab69ff7150f392fe548ecabbd8f5107dc2d1 (HEAD -> master)
  Author: Rupert <rupert@email.au>
  Date:   Tue Jun 6 18:58:02 2017 +1000

      blank project
```

I remember in a SUSE linux instance I needed to change the LESS value. [ANSI color in git is not displayed correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484167/ansi-color-in-git-is-not-displayed-correctly) but it seems to be a difference between ISE and the normal powershell...

Comment: PowerShell and PowerShell_ISE are based on different *hosts*. Normal PowerShell uses the Windows Console Host (same as cmd.exe) while PowerShell_ISE works differently, so there is no guarantee that command line application output will render in the same way. I read your question as "how do I get ISE to behave as PowerShell / cmd.exe"?

Comment: The following article on PowerShell hosts observes that some command-line tools don't work correctly in ISE, and is worth reading for anyone who comes by this question and hasn't heard about PS using different hosts:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4341.powershell-hosts.aspx