# Git opens editor with Ansi escape characters

Tags: git, command-line-interface, editor

When I last ran `git commit --amend` which opens up my editor I'm seeing all these strange characters which appear to be ANSI escape sequences or something. I'm not sure what I did or if it has to do with some setting in my .zshrc or .gitconfig. Whenever git opens my editor (vim), for example, when attempting to edit my git config `git config --global --edit` I get the same behavior. I don't know how to fix this. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling git via homebrew. I also `rm -rf ~/.gitconfig` to no avail.

Vim on its own works fine.

I found this similiar issue: [ANSI color in git is not displayed correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484167/ansi-color-in-git-is-not-displayed-correctly)

and tried `git config --global core.pager "less -R"` unsuccessfully as well.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, it was because I had recently installed NeoVim but still had git configured to use vim as my editor. Once I updated the config to use NeoVim: `git config --global core.editor nvim` all was well. Leaving this open for posterity in case anyone else makes a similar gaffe.