# Show multiline commit message with `git log --oneline`

Tags: git

I have a git commit message that includes 2 lines of text and a blank line.
`git log` shows the whole message, but `git log --oneline` shows only the 1st line.

How can `git log --oneline` to show the entire message (ignore the blank line, and append every other line)?

Full log:

```
$> git log
commit: d9ce3b...
Author: John Doe <john.doe@example.com>
Date:   Fri Mar 10 11:40:58 2023 -0500

   ticket number is #1234

   add a new css class in the select section.
```

Oneline variant is missing the last line of the message:

```
$> git log --oneline
d9ce3b ticket number is #1234
```

What I would like is:

```
d9ce3b ticket number is #1234 add a new css class in the select section.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show full Git commit message in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824863/show-full-git-commit-message-in-console)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Good tips, but this did not answer my question, specific to the use of `--oneline` with multiline commit messages that include blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there's no way to do that directly with git.

You can, however, use `awk` for this:

```
git log --oneline | awk '{cmd="echo -n "$1"; git log " $1 " --format=\" %B\" -n 1 | paste -sd \" \" "; system(cmd)}'
```