# Wrap Long git reflog Lines?

Tags: git, reflog

`git reflog` displays a single-line description, clipping it at the right margin.

```
74a8491 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from feature/x to feature/y
74a8491 HEAD@{1}: commit (merge): Merge branch 'feature/x' of https://github.com/
949d0e4 HEAD@{2}: ...
```

How can the entire reflog message be displayed, wrapped to take the minimum lines necessary (single-line for short descriptions)?

Answer (score 3):

[`git reflog`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) can take any [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) option you want.

If you want the full commit message associate with each git reflog entries, you can do a:

```
git reflog show --pretty=full
```

Or, for the "single-line for short descriptions"

```
git reflog show --pretty=format:"%h : %s"
```

You can force a wrap for long messages with the [`core.pager` config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697519/6309).

Comment: Good advice to use `--pretty`. Although the output of "full" is a bit verbose, it points the way to a possible solution using the other --pretty formatting options.

Comment: @Rubistro "a possible solution using the other `--pretty` formatting options": which I edited in my answer just after your edit of your question.

Comment: Ah... yes. still doesn't wrap, though.

Comment: @Rubistro even with core.pager option?

Comment: Yes, as the core.pager option does something, but messes up the first line (in OS X terminal, anyway). Great tip on using the left and right arrows to see the overflow (even without the core.pager setting), but in this particular case, I'm looking for a way to see everything wrapped on the single screen without flipping to the right and back.

Answer (score 2):

To emulate 'git reflog', adding the author, time ago date, and wrap long description lines:

```
git reflog show --pretty='%C(yellow)%h%Creset %gd %w(110,0,26)%gs %C(cyan)%cn%Creset %ar'
```

- `%h` is the short hash
- `%w(wrapwidth, firstLineIndent, indent)` causes the next field to be wrapped to the given width
- `%gs` is the reflog description
- `%cn` is the committer's name
- `%ar` is the date of the change in relative format (time ago)

#### Make it permanent:

To enable the command:

```
git r     # call it whatever you want
```

Put this into the ~/.gitconfig file:

[alias]
    r = reflog show --pretty='%C(yellow)%h%Creset %gd %w(110,0,26)%gs %C(cyan)%cn%Creset %ar'

(The alias can be named anything other than 'reflog' or an existing command.)

Comment: That seems more precise and complete than my answer. Well done. +1

Answer (score 1):

The usual pager is `less`, and you can toggle its line-wrapping option.  Type `-S` at the pager prompt.  `h` will give more gory details.

Comment: Beautiful. Although to make this the default behavior (using git config) in git 1.8.5.2, I had to use the form: `+-S`, i.e.: `git config --global core.pager "less -+S`