# How to view a long, one-line git commit message with git bash

Tags: git

A collaborator has added a very long one-line commit message to our shared repository.  I've tried viewing it using `git log` and `git show <hash>`, but in both cases the message runs off the edge of my screen.

How can I view his whole message using git from the bash command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wrap git commit comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119942/how-to-wrap-git-commit-comments)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`fold`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/fold.html) command:

```
git log | fold -w 80 -s
```

According to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25174/79307), you may need to replace `-w` with `-c`.

Answer (score 1):

Both `git log` and `git show` use your configured pager, by default.  It's your pager, not Git, that is doing the off-edge-of-screen management.

You can:

- temporarily change your pager: `git -c core.pager=cat show ...`, for instance;
- temporarily disable your pager: `git --no-pager show ...`, for instance;
- pipe the output, which by default disables pagers (but you can configure the system to always use the pager, which defeats this defeat method): `git show ... | cat`, for instance.

Besides these, you can use a `--pretty=format:...` or `--format=` directive to `git log` to specify how the commits are to be shown.  Using:

```
git log -1 --format=%s <hash>
```

will show that one commit (using the pager, unless you've disabled it) using a format that shows only the subject line.

Answer (score 0):

If your pager is `less`, and it is set up to chop long lines by default (*), you can change behavior of currently running `less` by pressing '-',  'S'.

*) see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-corepager for how default is set.